# How to get meta data out of mp3 files

Tags: php, mp3

Can anyone recommend a good standalone class (not part of PEAR) or another method for me to grab some basic meta data from about 1,400 MP3 files?

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/MP3_IDv2 can be used perfectly fine as a "standalone class" if need be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Works with both ID3 v1 and V2. Reads more than just id3 but should fit the bill.  You can also play with the following taken from http://www.htmlhelpcentral.com/messageboard/showthread.php?t=12006

```
<? 
class CMP3File { 
 var $title;var $artist;var $album;var $year;var $comment;var $genre; 
 function getid3 ($file) { 
  if (file_exists($file)) { 
   $id_start=filesize($file)-128; 
   $fp=fopen($file,"r"); 
   fseek($fp,$id_start); 
   $tag=fread($fp,3); 
   if ($tag == "TAG") { 
    $this->title=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->artist=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->album=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->year=fread($fp,4); 
    $this->comment=fread($fp,30); 
    $this->genre=fread($fp,1); 
    fclose($fp); 
    return true; 
   } else { 
    fclose($fp); 
    return false; 
   } 
  } else { return false; } 
 } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: GetID3 on sourceforge works but is a lot more than people might need. The CMP3File class you pasted works really great with ID3v1, but most mp3s these days are using v2 or v3. Here is a tutorial posted online on using PHP + ID3v3 tags (http://www.script-tutorials.com/id3-tags-reader-with-php/) -- I coupled this with audiojs HTML5 playlist player (http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) and it works like a dream.